# Как правильно перебирать строку в Си?

Tags: c, строки, while

Когда у нас есть строка и мы ищем какой-либо элемент, мы можем делать это с помощью счетчика i (`i++`) либо просто увеличивая адрес указателя (`str2++`). Результат будет один, хотя механизмы немного разные. Можно ли сказать что всегда можно использовать (`str++`) так как не нужно вводить дополнительную переменную i, т.е. меньше кода нужно писать?
И как правильно выбрать условие - `while(str1[i] !='\0')` или `while(str1[i])` или `while (*str1)`? Равноценны ли данные выражения?

```
int main() {
int i = 0;
  
char* str1 = "abcd";
char* str2 = "efgh";
while (str1[i] !='\0' )
  i++;
while (*str2)
  str2++;

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Во всех случаях у компилятора достаточно информации чтобы выдать один и тот же код - тот что с точки зрения компилятора наиболее оптимален. На x86 компилятор вместо циклов подставит одну инструкцию [SCASB](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/assembly_programming/assembly_scas_instruction.htm). В таких условиях нет смысла оптимизировать код руками. Пишите правильно, предоставляйте компилятору все данные - остальную работу он сделает сам.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`Можно ли сказать что всегда можно использовать (str++) так как не нужно вводить дополнительную переменную i, т.е. меньше кода нужно писать?`

Нет, нельзя. У вас теряется указатель на начало строки. Если он вам больше не нужен - такой метод подойдёт.

`Равноценны ли данные выражения?`
Посмотрите сгенерированный ассемблерный код. Он может быть одинаков, а может и нет - зависит от компилятора.